# Email service configuration that includes manual vetting of incoming messages

Tags: email

We have a senior relative who has long been happily using an email address at their own domain name, running on a more-or-less conventional POP+SMTP service.

Relative is now being regular plagued by scam emails, and have somewhat diminished perceptiveness in recognizing them. We don't want to discontinue email altogether, as relative uses it regularly to stay in touch with friends and so on. But it's at the point where we would like relative's emails to be vetted by one of us before allowing relative to see them.

So conceptually what we want is an email server configuration that would hold emails, not make them available to relative until one of us has logged in (say once a day), and endorsed the emails that are OK, and deleted the unwanted emails.

I'd appreciate ideas on how to actually implement something like this, either with POP/SMTP, or IMAP.

Edit to add: Relative is at a location remote from us, using his own computer. We can visit and configure that computer, but the email vetting can't involve regular or daily intervention in that computer's file system.

Comment: To the person who voted to close (based on "likely to prompt opinion-based answers":   What further facts would be helpful in my specification of the functionality I am looking for?  How would an answer that _in fact_ implements my request be based on opinion?  Obviously, a respondent would have the _opinion_ that their answer solves the problem.  How on earth could I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier with IMAP.

First, create a second email address within the system and give the relative access to that whilst preserving ability to send email with the original email address.

Second, remove the relatives permissions on the original email address.

Third, give yourself or others IMAP permissions to both email address and the IMAP structure.

When an email comes in to the original email address, you can review it and if acceptable, move it into the relatives new email box.

Biggest issue, but not difficult is to ensure you have permissions to access the IMAP struct.

Or...

Create a sieve rule which would, when an email arrives, writes the email into a separate folder which the relative does not have permissions, but others do.

Then once approved, you can move it into the correct inbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- what is "the IMAP structure", and what does access to it look like?

Comment: Quickie before I go to work... IMAP can contain sub-folders. If you have ever used Outlook and used sub-folders to organise your emails, that is based on IMAP, it's the same. The sieve rules are very easy to understand, it's just setting the permissions which you will have to read up on. I think many clients which support IMAP, also support creating sub-folders &setting the permissions.

Comment: yes I'm familiar with email directory structure for POP clients. And IMAP allows configuring "folders" on the server.  But I'm not following what interaction you're thinking about that solves our problem.  I don't know how we would move messages across folders in different accounts.  (Unless we were running the email server ourselves.)